# Catch Exception when File Upload is Canceled?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

I have an upload form where a user can upload files. When the user has submitted a form he can cancels the request as:

```
    // abort old ajax request
    if(xhrObject && xhrObject.readyState != 4){
        xhrObject.abort();
    }
```

When the request has been canceled the server throws the following error:

```
ERROR [/test].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/test] threw exception
Message: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
->>  371 | parseRequest in org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    126 | parseRequest in org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
->>  976 | makeAvailable in org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    886 | read      in     ''
|    101 | read . .  in java.io.InputStream
|     96 | copy      in org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams
|     66 | copy . .  in     ''
|    366 | parseRequest in org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase
|    126 | parseRequest in org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I tried to catch this error in my Controller as:

```
def save() {
try {
...
} catch (Exception ex) {...}
}
```

It turns out that this does not work.

**How can I catch the canceled upload in my action?**

Comment: My guess is that your action is actually never called.  Is there a reason you need to catch the exception?  Usually if the end user cancels the upload they won't see the exception anyways.

Comment: @hooknc The reason is that I cancel the upload when the user changes the file he wants to upload. So I want to cancel the old file ajax file upload that has been started and start the new ajax file upload.

Comment: There is some missing information here.  Let's dig a bit deeper.  You seems to have an javascript client that is making ajax Multipart Post requests.  You have behavior that if a user selects a different file, the first download cancels.  Does that sounds about right?  If so, what harm does the exception on the server cause?  Does the javascript client require a confirmation that the uploaded was canceled?  I guess, I'm not seeing the problem, having an exception during a canceled upload is pretty standard actually.

Comment: @hooknc you are right. The problem is that the javascript needs a confirmation that the download has been canceled to work as expected.

Comment: I was really hoping you wouldn't say that.  I guess, what does it matter if the cancel worked or not?  For the client, they should just move on, what [http response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) should the server return?  I personally think sending back a 500 is AOK in this case.  BUT, if you must absolutely return some sort of message, then you're going to either catch this exception in a filter or do something in a Spring Exception Resolver.